# how to parse index matrix using parsedelimeter in delphi

Tags: delphi, parsing, matrix

i want to parsing index matrix using space delimeter with this code

```
    Temp := TStringList.Create;
  Temp.LoadFromFile('training.txt');
  Row := 1;
  for I := 0 to Temp.Count-1 do
  begin
    S := Temp.Strings[I];
   ParseDelimited(Memo1.Lines, Trim(S), ' ');
    Inc(Row);
  end;
```

that code used to parsing index matrix that contain one space between the value,
but i have matrix that contain one and two spaces between the value? anybody can help me what should i do?

Comment: You keep posting questions about this mythical `ParseDelimited` and the refuse all exhortations to tell us what it is. Ask yourself why we should help you?

Comment: It's not this by any chance? http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/parsedelimited.htm

Comment: i have tried this method but  i don't know how to change the code so it can parsing one and two spaces in one matrix at once. can you help me?

Comment: Your edit does not help. `ParseDelimited` is not part of the Delphi RTL. Don't make us guess what it is.

Answer (score 1):

TStrings class has CommaText property. Read about it and use. It works properly with multiple spaces between data chunks:

```
var
  Temp, TempList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Temp := TStringList.Create;
  try
    TempList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Temp.LoadFromFile('training.txt');
      for i := 0 to Temp.Count - 1 do begin
        TempList.CommaText := Temp[i];
        Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(TempList);
      end;
    finally
      TempList.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Temp.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: you right, i have tried this code and success, thank you